# Creating a button with an icon in the middle

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to replicate the look of the Like and Comment button in this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibWsE.png

I understand how to create a shape, but I'm not sure how I could add the image icon in the middle of the button (and the "Like" text).

Here's the shape layout I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">

            <solid android:color="@color/gray"/>
            <size android:width="40dp" android:height="24dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

For the like button, how do I add the drawable heart icon I have next to the text "Like". And for the comment button, how do I add the drawable comment icon I have and center it in the button?

Comment: I think you just want an `ImageButton`, which can have the heart icon and "Like" built into it.

Comment: All views are clickable, you can use anything.

Comment: @DigitalNinja What if I wanted a button with variable-length text? For example, a button where the value of the text in the center could be just `1` or `1,000,000`?

Comment: @user5188154 Then you can do as Jared suggested and make a layout that holds the text clickable. You might have to do some work to readjust the size of the layout depending on the text length though. I've never ran into an issue where I didn't know the max length of a text view.

Comment: That doesn't really solve my initial issue of not knowing how to add the image icon into the shape.

Answer (score 4):

This is simple

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/comments"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_grey_bg"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

and here is rounded_corner_grey_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#d3d3d3"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dip"
        android:color="#d3d3d3" />
    <corners android:radius="5dip"/>/>
</shape>
```

[image]